# Boost + Expire: Front Page not expiring from cache

Tags: nodes, caching

I am using [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) and [Cache Expiration](https://drupal.org/project/expire). My site generates nodes automatically and adds them via `node_save()`. I have setup Expire to get triggered on node insert, update and delete and to let the front page and the node page expire (see screenshot).

The problem is now: When the site is under high traffic, the front page does not get expired. When the traffic is low, the expiration works as it should.

I could reproduce this error even locally: While adding a node, I let `wget` constantly accessing the front page on my local host. As on the production server, the front page did not expire.

My hunch for the reason now is that the following happens within some milliseconds:

1. When calling `node_save()`, the new node get only scheduled to be saved but not saved yet.
2. The cache although, gets flushed immediately.
3. A new request to the front page is made, it gets delivered and its old version gets cached again.
4. The scheduled node save operation finally gets written to the database. But it has no effect to the front page, since it is already cached.

Do you think that my hunch is correct? If yes, what should I do? And if no, what could be the reason instead and what should I do?

[image: Cache expiration settings]

Comment: Hm, interesting problem. I'm not too familiar with boost for D7, but in D6 there is a setting called "Overwrite the cached file if it already exits" in the "Boost advanced settings" section. Does that exist in D7 and if so, have you tried that?

Comment: anther option might be to use the crawler at defined intervals.

Comment: Just tried to find that option but it seems that it doesn't exist anymore. There's even no "advanced settings" section anymore. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try to add the `<front>` page to the rules action "Clear URL(s) from the page cache":

[image: Rules: Clear URL(s) from the page cache]

Comment: Thank you. I did. As well as 
`domain.com/start`
Still the same effect. I went down to a lower number of hours as Cache Lifetime, since then it got better, though not resolved.